# HttpServerErrorException.InternalServerError does not catch the Error 500 from the Http Request Resttemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I am currently working on a service that hit another service from another team, which gives the response code 500 when the service has no data to be sent. At first, I can utilize the `HttpServerErrorException.InternalServerError` to catch the exception and get the response body. However, this did not work as it used to. That error was not caught by that Exception and when I tried using `catch (Exception e)`, it also caught nothing and let it through that  makes the service not running correctly..

Below is the code, what is actually wrong from my code below? How should I handle that 500 response code?

```
        Map resultMap1;
        try {
            resultMap1 = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, Map.class);
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException.InternalServerError e) {
            resultMap1 = new HashMap();
            resultMap1.put("errorMessage", e.getMessage());
            return resultMap1;
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException.GatewayTimeout e) {
            throw new AppException(
                    GATEWAY_TIMEOUT_CD,
                    GATEWAY_TIMEOUT_MSG +": "+ url,
                    null
            );
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException.BadGateway e) {
            throw new AppException(
                    BAD_GATEWAY_CD,
                    BAD_GATEWAY_MSG +": "+ url,
                    null
            );
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException.ServiceUnavailable e) {
            throw new AppException(
                    SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE_CD,
                    "The service "+ url +" was unavailable.",
                    null
            );
        }
        Map returnMap = new HashMap(); // this is to be the result from my service
        switch (resultMap.get("content_type")){      // In this one, I get NullPointerException      
            // Here would be selection how the content should be treated, different content have different treatment            
        }
```

I know that the NullPointerException can actually be handled by adding ELSE or another case, However, I curious about why the Exception wasn't caught well as it supposed to be.

Comment: can you post more details like stack trace or what is the Url you are calling. What is the error you are facing? Instead of having multiple try catch block , have you checked for `ResponseErrorHandler`

Comment: I have checked about it, however, as you see that when I got the 500, I need to send the result as it's normal, because it's really normal (just negative case, not really server error). I cannot throw exception for it because it should just be ignored..

Comment: Can you post error stacktrace?

Comment: The error is actually NullPointerException... That try catch chain was actually just passed through without being caught as if there wasn't HTTP Response 500 occured, when the InternalServerError Exception should catch it

Comment: As requested by others also , Please post your stacktrace and debug results to get more idea about what exactly happening.